# Best color for pool cover

Tags: thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

I couldn't find a stack* forum for pools, so I hope this is the next best place to post.

I have an 18 foot diameter above ground pool in the north west, and I don't like the pool cover that came with it.

I built a deck at the water surface level, about 4' above ground, and now have a concern about someone falling onto the covered pool and moving on to their next life.

I started thinking about 2' x 2' squares of bubble wrap (or some size that won't kill someone) but was wondering about the color and efficiency.

I always thought black would be best as it would get more heat from the sun. I must leave the pump on to circulate the heat to the lower part of the pool.

I have a couple of questions...

1. I read some people like clear as the sunlight goes through the cover and heat the pool walls and bottom and more heat goes into the water. (I don't know if that is true as the walls are white, and the bottom is a light blue.)
2. Bubble wrap will have the issue that the sun will heat the first layer of plastic, and the air bubble will insulate the water from the sun. On the other hand, the bubble wrap will work better at night as it will hold the heat in better.
3. Is there a 2 layer bubble wrap with clear on one side and black on the other? Placed clear side up, the sun can penetrate the clear and heat the part in contact with the water.
4. At night, is black better then clear? Which will radiate heat into the air more?
5. Is there such a thing as a thermal diode. Let the heat in, but don't let the heat out. I have never heard of such a thing.

I hope to open a bag of worms and get lots of discussion on the various topics of heat loss and heat transfer.

I totally get there is a lot of heat (and chemicals) lost to evaporation so covered is better.

Thanks, Mark.

Comment: I have a retail pool cover that is like large, thick, tough bubble wrap. It is clear on top and silvery gray on the bottom to heat the air inside, making a warm blanket floating on top of the pool.